# VS2015 - referenced assembly yields C2869 error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, .net-assembly

I am building a DLL with Visual Studio 2015, in C++.

The Visual Studio project for the DLL references a .NET assembly. (One of the files in the project is a C++/CLI file.)
This .NET assembly is provided by a third party, and they have made available a new version of the assembly.

Building the project with the old version of the assembly works fine, but when I build with the new version of the assembly, I get the following errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(24): error C2869: 'std::errc': has already been defined to be a namespace
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(109): error C2869: 'std::io_errc': has already been defined to be a namespace
```

Looking at the old and new versions of the assembly with ildasm I can see that the new assembly defines an enum `errc` in the namespace `std::errc`, whereas the old assembly defines enum errc in namespace `std`. There are similar differences for io_errc too.

It seems that the build process reads the referenced assembly before it attempts to compile `system_error`, resulting in the errors above. Is there anything I can do to reconcile the new assembly with Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for this issue is to `#define` the offending items to something else, before including the STL headers.

```
#define errc Errc
#define io_errc Io_errc
#include <system_error>
```

See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee40b218-350a-4b21-ae73-28838ccca2ea/ccli-error-c2869-stdpointersafety-has-already-been-defined-to-be-a-namespace?forum=vcgeneral.